# viewResolver with more folders inside of WEB-INF/jsp is not working in spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" /> <!--  avoid '???' -->
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

if i create other subfolders under jsp , for instance
/WEB-INF/jsp/reports , /WEB-INF/jsp/insertions

how should i configure now the viewResolver to can resolve these new sub folders??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Say you have a jsp `test.jsp` under `/WEB-INF/jsp/reports`

From your controller return

```
@RequestMapping("/helloWorld")
    public String helloWorld(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello World!");
        return "reports/test";
    }
```

Comment: very dapper sir

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your the Tiles layout system

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer" id="tilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/layouts/layouts.xml</value>
            <!-- Scan views directory for Tiles configurations -->
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/**/views.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Then you create the views.xml where you have all the routes of your view to link with your ModelAndView in the controller.

views.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.1//EN"
    "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd">

     <tiles-definitions>

       <definition name="refreshActivityPlan" extends="basic.ajax-requirejs">
               <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/views/common/activity_plan/activityPlanView.jsp"/>
        </definition>


       </tiles-definitions>
```

Then finally in your controller:

```
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("refreshActivityPlan");
    mav = getModelAndView(id, subStep, mav);
    return mav;
```

Answer (score 0):

From your controller return values like reports/xxx or insertions/yyy

Answer (score 0):

View resolver picks up the prefix you have configured in XML file or java configuration and it prefixes it with the jsp file name you have provided,

here in this case resolver is looking for /WEB-INF/jsp/test.jsp which is not available.

> replace that "test" with "reports/test" while creating ModelAndView
>   object.